# ADD A DATE IN A INSERT INTO

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm trying to add a date when a tag from plc change but I read only "undefined" on date's row

```
msg.topic = `insert into plc_valori_tag(numero_macchina, tag_macchina, 
valore_tag, data) values
(
'5',
'peso_materia_prima_lotto',
${msg.payload},
${msg.payload[new Date()]}
)`;
return msg;
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the code *as text* in the question. Images are too hard to read. And also include which database you are using in the tags.

Comment: edited with the code

Comment: Edit the question to show the input message JSON as well

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be :

```
msg.topic = `insert into plc_valori_tag(
  numero_macchina, 
  tag_macchina, 
  valore_tag, 
  data
) values (
  '5',
  'peso_materia_prima_lotto',
  `${msg.payload}`, // or JSON.stringify(msg.payload)
  Date.now()  // or new Date()
);`;
return msg;
```

In your code, `msg.payload[new Date()]` means that your looking for the "2019-01-21 15:54:32" property of the `msg.payload` object, which should not exist in the real world...

And also you use ${msg.payload} as a template literal, you missed the `` character but you should prefer the `JSON.stringify` solution if `msg.payload` is an object.